# Bulk rename files on media device matched with regex on Windows

Tags: batch-file

I feel like I could do this fairly easily on a linux machine with bash, but I don't have enough experience with Batch to do it.

Basically, a lot of the music files on my phone start with the track number :

```
01 - a song
02 - another song
03 a third song (different format)
```

I can easily get all of the files by a regex match:

```
dir /b | findstr /i "^[0-9]+ .*"
```

And then I'm assuming I should assign these values to a variable. But can I do a for loop over them by just doing

```
for %filename in %var
     ren file [something here]
```

The only thing I have issues with is getting onto the media device (how does windows handle this under the hood?) and removing the prefix, while dealing with the two possible formats (detecting the '-' shouldn't be hard). I would be able to do it with sed, but I don't know the batch equivalent.

Comment: Not sure how to access the device. But if you figure that out, then you should look into [JREPL.BAT - a regex find/replace tool for renaming files](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that does not require any 3rd party exe files.

Comment: That's very helpful if I can figure out how to use it - doesn't look like the easiest tool in the world

Comment: If you can use sed and other unix tools, then you shouldn't have much trouble. Depending on the complexity of your situation, you may need to also learn a bit of javascript. Be sure to scan through the entire thread, and pay attention to the examples. If you have a specific name transformation that you cannot figure out, then you can post a question here or on DosTips. Or you could edit this question with additional details.

Comment: I suggest to use shareware file manager Total Commander which has a built-in multi-rename tool which supports even regular expression replace for directory/file renames and you can even see the new file names before running the rename. Such a tool avoids the requirement to code file and directory renames as Windows batch script. Total Commander supports also devices accessed via MTP - Media Transfer Protocol not accessible within Windows command process.

Comment: The rename would be trivial in PowerShell, `rename-item` and `move-item` take `-NewName` scriptblock parameters to process the names. However, in your quest to be as vague as possible, you haven't said what your renaming operation is, or what your phone is. My guess is it's something which doesn't appear as a drive letter, only as an Explorer extension, and therefore you won't be able to do this at all easily...?

Comment: I posted a file renamer script as an answer. As far as accessing the filesystem on an MTP device from the cmd console, the only solution I can think of is don't. There are several forum threads and other community type posts of people asking how to do it, struggling for several pages, then concluding it isn't possible. You can only either use Explorer to move your media files to the pc, rename, then move back; or set up an FTP server on your phone and map it as a drive over WiFi on your pc. I'd probably just do the move thing myself.

Comment: It does seem like accessing the MTP device is not possible/not easy to do. The rename script is cool though, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been meaning to do this for a while anyway.

There's a handy [Perl rename script](https://gist.github.com/javiermon/3939556) written years ago by Larry Wall that I often use to rename files via regexp.  But since I rarely have need for Perl in Windows, and installing Perl just for this one script seems like a waste, I always thought it'd be a good idea to rewrite prename using native Windows scripting languages.

Hopefully if there are any bugs, they won't be too debilitating.  I didn't test the script a whole lot, but it seems to work fine for basic usage where the files you're renaming live in your current working directory.  Bonus: backreferences work in your replacement text.  Wooo.

#### Example usage

```js
prename.bat -v "s/searchRXP/replacement/flags" filemask
```

See `prename.bat -h` in a console window for full usage help.

#### prename.bat

```js
<!-- : prename.bat -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/38191137/1683264
@echo off & setlocal

rem // ensure flags and other vars begin undefined
for %%I in (v n f h show filemask search replace flags) do set %%I=

rem // organize arguments
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript //nologo //job:args "%~f0?.wsf" %*') do set "%%~I"
if defined h goto usage
if defined invalid (
    echo Unrecognized option: %invalid%
    goto usage
)
if not defined filemask goto usage
if not defined search goto usage
if defined v set "show=1"
if defined n set "show=1"

rem // expand wildcards
for %%I in (%filemask%) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%# in ('cscript //nologo //job:newname "%~f0?.wsf" "%%~I"') do (
        if defined show echo %%~I -^> %%~#
        if not defined n if not "%%~fI"=="%%~f#" (
            >NUL (
                if defined f (move /y "%%~I" "%%~#") else ren "%%~I" "%%~nx#"
            )
        )
    )
)

goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filelist]
echo    -v shows verbose output
echo    -n performs a simulation only
echo    -f forces overwriting existing files
echo    perlexpr is a Perl-compatible regular expression
echo    filelist can contain wildcards
echo;
echo Example:
echo    %~nx0 -n "s/([^\.]+)$/\1.cmd/i" *.bat
echo This would simulate renaming every .bat file extension to .bat.cmd
goto :EOF

: end batch begin JScript hybrid code -->
<package>
    <job id="args">
        <script language="JScript">
            var args = {
                    v: 0,
                    n: 0,
                    f: 0,
                    h: 0,
                    search: '',
                    replace: '',
                    flags: '',
                    filemask: ''
                };

            for (var i=0; i<WSH.Arguments.length; i++) {
                if (/^[\/-](.)/.test(WSH.Arguments(i))) {
                    if (typeof args[RegExp.$1] === 'undefined')
                        args.invalid = WSH.Arguments(i);
                    args[RegExp.$1] = 1;
                }
                else if (/^s(\W)(.+)\1(.*)\1(.*)/.test(WSH.Arguments(i))) {
                    args.search = RegExp.$2;
                    args.replace = RegExp.$3;
                    args.flags = RegExp.$4;
                }
                else args.filemask += ';' + '"' + WSH.Arguments(i) + '"';
            }
            for (var i in args) if (args[i]) WSH.Echo(i + '=' + args[i]);
        </script>
    </job>
    <job id="newname">
        <script language="JScript">
            var env = WSH.CreateObject('WScript.Shell').Environment('Process'),
                search = env('search'),
                repl = env('replace'),
                flags = env('flags');

            WSH.Echo(WSH.Arguments(0).replace(
                new RegExp(search, flags),
                function(full, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) {
                    var backref = [full, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9];
                    return repl.replace(
                        /[\\$](\d)/g,
                        function(full, $1) { return backref[$1]; }
                    );
                }
            ));
        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```