# Window File Batch Rename from Spaces to Underscore

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to use a batch to rename a file from "aaa aaa.doc" to "aaa_aaa.doc"

I've written a script in the past to rename "aaa_aaa.doc" to "aaa aaa.doc"

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*_*) do (
  set file=%%a
  ren "!file!" "!file:_= !"
)
```

How to modify from " " to "_" and ignore special symbol?

Comment: Try `rename "aaa aaa.doc" "aaa_aaa.doc"`, it does exactly what your question asked.

Comment: You might find [prename.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38191137/1683264) useful.  Example: `prename /v "s/ /_/g" *`

Comment: When you replace all `_` by spaces, then replace all spaces by `_`, you might not have the original situation (think of spaces occurring in the original names, if any)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to reverse all steps and quote names with possible spaces.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in ("* *") do (
  set "file=%%a"
  ren "%%a" "!file: =_!"
)
```

Answer (score -2):

try this!

```
ren "current_filename.ext" "new_filename.ext"
```