# Renaming files in numerical series

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-rename

So I am using an application that creates a series of `.tif` files with very annoying filenames that do not sort correctly in alphanumerical order. I have no way to change the behavior of this commercial software, so I must use my own creativity to rename the files so they may be processed externally in the correct order. For example, the files created look like this:

`image.tif`, `image(2).tif`, `image(3).tif`, ..., `image(9).tif`, `image(10).tif`, ..., `image(n).tif`

Where *n* is an integer not less than 2. The first file has no number in parenthesis. Sorted alphanumerically, for example, the list would look like:

`image.tif`, `image(10).tif`, `image(100).tif`, `image(1000)`, `image(2).tif`, ...

Obviously while this is the correct alphanumerical order, it's the incorrect numerical order. So with the aid of some batch commands, I created this:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

ren "image.tif" "a.tif"
ren "image(1).tif" "b.tif"
ren "image(2).tif" "c.tif"
ren "image(3).tif" "d.tif"
ren "image(4).tif" "e.tif"
ren "image(5).tif" "f.tif"
ren "image(6).tif" "g.tif"
ren "image(7).tif" "h.tif"
ren "image(8).tif" "i.tif"
ren "image(9).tif" "j.tif"

set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.tif') do (
  ren "%%i" "!a!.tif" 
  set /a a+=1
)
```

This at least corrects the names of the first ten files, as I often process less than 100 files. The *for* loop is a snippet I found here on stackoverflow, it renames the alphanumeric files into integers starting with 1 up to the number of files.

Problem I run into is that this loop still creates `1.tif`, `10.tif`, and `100.tif` that would come before `2.tif`.

I've seen the use of `%02d` to format numbers into 01, 02, 10, etc. Does anyone know how to syntactically include that in the loop shown above?

Or if anyone can figure a more elegant method to rename these files into a suitable alphanumeric order, it would be greatly appreciated. I have the feeling my solution is very kludgey.

Answer (score 1):

The `%02d` convention for padding numbers is a `printf` thing, not really applicable to the Windows cmd environment or batch scripting.  PowerShell has [something similar](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx), but not pure batch.  However, you can zero-pad numerals pretty easily using [variable substring manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php).

```
set /a a=0
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b *.tif') do (
    set "idx=00!a!"
    ren "%%~I" "!idx:~-3!%%~xI"
    set /a a += 1
)
```

If you'd prefer to keep the naming convention of `image(idx).tif` while ensuring the TIF files remain in their intended sequential order, a lazy solution might be to use [prename.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38191137/1683264) and rename with regexps.

```
prename /v "s/\((\d)\)/(00\1)/" *.tif
prename /v "s/\((\d\d)\)/(0\1)/" *.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize "i" variable with the desired number of digits as zeros
set i=1000

rem Process the files in creation date-time order
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /A-D /OD /B *.tif') do (

   rem Increment the number: "1001"...
   set /A i+=1

   rem Omit first digit in number: "1", use the rest: "001"...
   ren "%%a" "image(!i:~1!).tif"

)
```

Comment: why not `set/a i=100000` and `set digits=3` and then `ren "%%a" "image(!i:~-%digits%!).tif"` so only need to change *digits* if file number grows?

Comment: @elzooilogico: Because it is simpler to write `!i:~1!` that `!i:~-%digits%!`. The first form just depends on `i` variable, so you only need to change `i` if file number grows. In your example, if `digits` would have a value greater than `5`, you need to _also_ change `i` to include more zeros (and include _many_ zeros in `i` that will not be used is just _ugly_).

Comment: Yes, I see now. La próxima vez, leeré con más atención.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set /a max=99&set /a numlen=2
if exist "image(100).tif" set /a max=999&set /a numlen=3
for /L %%a in (1,1,%max%) do if exist "image(%%a).tif" set /a newnum=1000+%%a&if not exist "image(!newnum:~-%numlen%!).tif" echo(ren "image(%%a).tif" "image(!newnum:~-%numlen%!).tif"
set /a max+=1
echo(ren "image.tif" "image(!newnum:~-%numlen%!).tif"
```

[untested]

If "image(100).tif" exists, then we need to rename to (001)..(999). If not, to (01)..(99), so then number-length will be 3 or 2.

for each of the names 1..max, if the file exists, calculate 1000+the file number;take the last 3 or 2 characters and rename. Only attempt to rename if the destination name does not exist, so (6) will be renamed to (006) or (06), (15) to (05) or skipped as (15)=(15) and (123) will also be skipped as (123)=(123)
Finally, rename the `image.tif` file to (000) or (00)

Note that this will simply `echo` the required commands to allow verification. Change the `echo(ren` to `ren` when verified to actually perform the rename.

Comment: Just a quick observation: `set /a` lets you do compound assignments, like `set /a "max = 99, numlen = 2"`.  Also, in your `for /L` line, `%max` is missing a percent symbol.

Comment: @rojo: good spotting. Missing `%` fixed (using laptop while main machine is being fixed - can't handle the keyboard...). `set/a` is a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

In `cmd` there are no format strings like `%02d`. However, you can use [`dir /B`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to retrieve a plain list of files, [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to filter for those having a parenthesised numeric suffix in their names or no such suffix at all, [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to capture the resulting file names and split them into tokens relying on `(`, `)`, and [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) to do the actual left-zero-padding, like in the following example:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_LOCATION=."    & rem // (directory containing the files to rename)
set "_PATTERN=*.tif" & rem // (search pattern for the files to rename)
set /A "_DIGITS=4"   & rem // (number of proposed digits from 1 to 10)
set "_REGEX1=^[^()][^()]*([0-9][0-9]*)\.tif$" & rem // (filter expression)
set "_REGEX2=^[^()][^()]*\.tif$"              & rem // (filter expression)
rem // (the filter expressions ensure wrongly named files not to be processed)

rem // Build zero-padding string:
set "PAD=0000000000" & call set "PAD=%%PAD:~-%_DIGITS%%%"
rem // Loop through all matching files:
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=()" %%A in ('
    dir /B /O:N "%_PATTERN%" ^| findstr /I /R /C:"%_REGEX1%" /C:"%_REGEX2%"
') do (
    rem // Check if current file name contains a parenthesised numeric suffix:
    if not "%%B"=="" (
        rem // Numeric suffix found, so store file name parts and pad number:
        set "LEFT=%%A" & set "MID=%PAD%%%B" & set "RIGHT=%%C"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        ECHO rename "!LEFT!(%%B)!RIGHT!" "!LEFT!(!MID:~-%_DIGITS%!)!RIGHT!"
        endlocal
    ) else (
        rem // No numeric suffix encountered, so append zero-suffix:
        ECHO rename "%%A" "%%~nA(%PAD%)%%~xA"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

After having successfully verified the appropriate output of the script, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` command** to actually rename any files.

The script renames a file like `image.tif` to `image(0000).tif` (supposing there is no file named `image(0).tif`, originally). If you do not want that to happen, simply remove the `/C:"%_REGEX2%"` part from the `findstr` command line.