# Error handling in batch files

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, rename

I'm working on a script to automate a couple tasks. Essentially, it just renames files if they exist. However, these files are critical to the operation of some other software. If renaming a file fails, or if it cannot find file, i would like it to say which file it was. However, the REN command isn't very descriptive when it fails. I know that if it fails, it raises ERRORLEVEL to 1. Is there any other information i can get from the failure, like the file name? Or is it pretty much just a success or fail?

Machines this will be running on are Windows 7 and up, so powershell is also an option if necessary but i would prefer batch.

Thanks

Comment: It's succeed or fail. There's no information available about which file caused the failure.

Comment: All you need is to append a conditional execution command after the ren echoing the file trying to rename. `Ren filea.txt fileb.txt || Echo Ren filea.txt fileb.txt failed`

Comment: I'm bewildered by everything on this page.  It seems to me that you already have the filename captured as your iterative variable, don't you?  I mean, if you're looping through files to perform renames using something like `for %%I in (*) do ren "%%~fI" "%%~nI.bak"` or similar, right?  Why not just `... do (ren "%%~fI" "%%~nI.bak" || echo Renaming %%~nxI failed)` or similar?  Possibly related, you might find [prename.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38191137/1683264) useful for batch renames.

Answer (score 3):

As [Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white) points out in a comment on the question, the **error messages emitted by `cmd.exe`'s `ren` command do *not* include the filename(s) involved**.

**PowerShell**, by contrast, provides **verbose error messages that *do* include filenames**.
Take the following sample script:

```
# Create helper sample files.
$tempFiles = "$env:TEMP\foo", "$env:TEMP\bar"
$null = New-Item -Type File $tempFiles

# Try to rename a nonexistent item.
Rename-Item \no\such -NewName foo

# Try to rename to a file that already exists.
Rename-Item $env:TEMP\foo -NewName bar

# Clean up the sample files.
Remove-Item $tempFiles
```

If you save the above to a `*.ps1` file and run it (assuming you have [permitted scripts to run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies)), you'll see the following error output:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at '\no\such' does not exist.
At C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\pg\pg.ps1:8 char:5
+     Rename-Item \no\such -NewName foo
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\pg\pg.ps1:11 char:5
+     Rename-Item $env:TEMP\foo -NewName bar
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\foo:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

While the output is verbose, it does contain all relevant information, and you can even inspect it *programmatically*, via the automatic `$Error` variable, which contains all errors that were reported in the session in reverse chronological order (`$Error[0]` contains the most *recent* error).

Not that, by default, the PowerShell script will *continue* to run when these errors happen, because they are considered *non-terminating*.

- The simplest way to cause the script to *abort* right away is to start your script with line `$ErrorActionPreference= 'Stop'`.
- Alternatively, you can use `-ErrorAction Stop` on a *per-command* basis.

Run [`Get-Help about_Preference_Variables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables) and [`Get-Help about_CommonParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

as already noted, `ren` working with wildcards don't tell you *which* file failed. So you have to process each file individually. Thanksfully, there are commands for doing so: `for` and `forfiles`.

```
for %%a in (*) do ren "%%a" "destination.ext" 2>nul || echo FAILED: %%a
```

this tries to rename every file to "destination.ext", which works fine for the very first of them.
Renaming the rest of the files will fail (destination already existing).
`||` is a *"if previous command failed, then"* operator.
`2>nul` removes the errormessage (useless for you, as it doesn't tell you the filename)

(Note: this is syntax for batchfiles. If you try it directly on command line,
replace each `%%a` with `%a`)

Comment: Like `||` to display a custom message in case of an error, Any way to display custom message for success case as well?

Comment: @Vivek `&&`. You can combine them too: `command && echo success || echo fail`